# How to select only the child if the element has a parant on tap in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I want to get element code by touching it in a webview and sending the code to my app .
I achieved that but anytime i click an element that has a parant like a div
They both get selected

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poJZh.jpg)

**Java Code **

```
final WebSettings settings = myWebView.getSettings();

        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                final String injectedJs = "javascript:(function(){" + injectedJs() + "})()";
                myWebView.loadUrl(injectedJs);
            }
        });



myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(
                new Object() {
                    @JavascriptInterface
                    public void onClick(String param) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, param, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                "appHost"
        );
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/data.html");
```

**Javascript Code**

```
var lastSelectedItem = null;

var showHighlighted = function(/* HTML element */view, /*boolean */highlighted) {
    if (view) {
        view.style.cssText = highlighted? 'background-color: #ADD8E6; ' :' ';
    }
};

/* This new method, _addEventListener and _eventClick are the same as yours */
Object.prototype.each = function (fn, bind) {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                    if (i in this) {
                        fn.call(bind, this[i], i, this);
                    }
                }
            };

var _addListener = document.addEventListener || document.attachEvent,
    _eventClick = window.addEventListener ? 'click' : 'onclick';

/* I changed the element selection criteria, but you can change it back easily.
   I am adding event listeners all the leaf elements in the DOM. */
var elements = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
elements.each(function (el) {
    
        _addListener.call(el, _eventClick, function () {
            /* First, deal with the previously selected item*/
            showHighlighted(lastSelectedItem, false);
            
            /* Update the selected item reference */
            lastSelectedItem = el;


            /* Finally, deal with the previously selected item*/
            showHighlighted(lastSelectedItem, true);
            appHost.onClick(el.outerHTML.replace(el.innerHTML , ' '));
        }, false);
    
});
```

As you can see in the picture i click on the button and the code gets both the button and the div
How can i make it to only get the button even if the button has a parant?

Comment: Java ≠ JavaScript

Comment: No you are not right its not what am saying

Comment: That's what you falsely tagged it as though ...